# this.item on a Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to understand where the `this.item` is coming from on this Backbone View:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        var date = new Date();
        this.date = date;
        this.month = date.getMonth();
        this.day = date.getDay();
        this.year = date.getFullYear();
        this.calendar = new calendar();
        _.bindAll(this);
    },

    showActivityItem: function(e) {
        var target = $(e.currentTarget);
        var id = target.attr("data-id");
        var item = this.item;
    }
});
```

The `item` appears to be a Backbone Model and I'm OK with that except how did it get assigned to the `item` property.

When I output the item in the console, I get:

```
child {cid: "c85", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c85"
collection: child
__proto__: Surrogate
```

showActivityItem is being called per event:

```
    events: {
        'click #activityList .boxEntry': 'showActivityItem'
    },
```

There is no code in the class that does so. Is `item` some undocumented accessor for a Backbone model in a Backbone view? It is not in the list of View properties one on the Backbone website.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that working code? There is not such a thing like the item property, so the model has to be assigned on initialize.

Comment: This is just an abbreviated version of the code. I've added the initialize method. As you can see, it is not being assigned there, thus my confusion on how it is being assigned. It's not being assigned anywhere in the view. I suppose it is possible that it is being assigned outside of the view.

Comment: Could you do `console.log(item)`? Because it should be undefined...

Comment: Can you show us when `showActivityItem` is being called? It looks like it's a callback from a jQuery event. Maybe the context (this) is not the one of the view itself, but the one passed by jQuery.

Comment: @Puigcerber I've updated the question to include `console.log(item)`.

Comment: @gbsice I've update the question to include when the `showActivityItem` is being called.

Comment: `item` is definitely *not* defined by Backbone, which you can easily verify by searching its [source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html)

Comment: Yeah, that definitely looks like a Backbone model. How are you creating that view? Somewhere in your code has to be a reference to the item property.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere outside of the code you've shown, your code is (perhaps inadvertently) adding an `.item` property to the view.

```
var model = new ItemModel(...);

// ...

var view = new ItemView({model: model});

// ...

view.item = model;
```

It is certainly true that nothing in Backbone itself defines a property named `item`, which you can verify with a search of the [source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html). Since you are using standard Backbone event delegation (unless there is some code you haven't included), then `this` in the event handler will be set to the view itself.